# removeChild Function Not Working with setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, removechild

I am trying to build an animation that will display a series of images sequentially, but am running into trouble with the removeChild command and can't seem to figure out how to stop the images from displaying before the next ones appear. I can't use jQuery, as this code will interface with Qualtrics, which doesn't have jQuery. The code it below, and you can also access a JSFiddle of it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cbjrobertson/xrq1L4od/). I am absolutely a beginner and any help at all would be very appreciated!

```
 ////Animate\\\\\


var imageLinks = ["http://i.imgur.com/iUjHm4e.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/89Bh81C.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/qKecE0F.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/s5LzrE1.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/thRmkE8.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/mjfqeKv.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/w9EpXNq.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/b2rP5RQ.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/NDLm5QQ.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/7nohNKf.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/4Qtz8KB.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/xTwSsBe.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/KwXNQjR.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/5BVvvci.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/bU0jnnD.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/YKy6K6u.jpg",

];

function display(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function remove(img) {
    document.body.removeChild(img);
}



i = 0;

function animation_loop() {
    im = display(imageLinks[i]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < imageLinks.length) {
            animation_loop();
        }
    }, 50);
    remove(imageLinks[i]);
};


animation_loop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
                    var imageLinks=["http://i.imgur.com/iUjHm4e.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/89Bh81C.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/qKecE0F.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/s5LzrE1.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/thRmkE8.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/mjfqeKv.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/w9EpXNq.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/b2rP5RQ.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/NDLm5QQ.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/7nohNKf.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/4Qtz8KB.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/xTwSsBe.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/KwXNQjR.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/5BVvvci.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/bU0jnnD.jpg",
                    "http://i.imgur.com/YKy6K6u.jpg",
            ];
            function display(src)
            {
                    var img=document.createElement("img");
                    img.src=src;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                    return img;
            }
            function remove(img)
            {
                    document.body.removeChild(img);
            }
            var i=0;
            function animation_loop()
            {
                    var img=display(imageLinks[i]);
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                            i++;
                            if(i < imageLinks.length)
                            {
                                    animation_loop();
                                    remove(img);
                            }
                    }, 5000);
            }
            animation_loop();
```

You need to return DOM object after creating it in Display function to be used in remove method. I have executed remove method after reexecuting animation_loop-self function to understand the execution flow..

Answer (score 0):

You pass string from `imageLinks` to `remove` method

You need to store image created in `display()` and remove it. You have almost done that) Here's working code:

```
function animation_loop() {
    im = display(imageLinks[i]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < imageLinks.length) {
            animation_loop();
        }
    }, 50);
    remove(im);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to be removing the image, just displaying each sequentially below the others. And if I return img in the function display, it doesn't run...